# Как получить значение из json файла, указывая его через аргумент?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, discord

Я пытаюсь получить значение из json,я пытаюсь указать значение через args[0] но у меня не выходит, я получаю вместо полного слова undefined, как мне это сделать правильно ?

index.js

```
const jsondb = require('./data/dbwords.json');
const input = args[0]

message.channel.send('Вы имели ввиду слово: ' + jsondb.input + " ?");
```

dbwords.json

```
{
 "прив": "привет",
 "спс": "спасибо",
 "крч": "короче",
 "пж": "пожалуйста"
}
```

Comment: что выдаёт `console.log(args)`

Comment: Я пишу `/word прив` и хочу получить "Вы имели ввиду слово: привет ?", но я пполучаю "Вы имели ввиду слово: undefined ?", при использование команды `console.log(args[0])`, я получаю "прив"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте **jsondb[input]** вместо **jsondb.input**

Comment: О это сработало, спасибо!

Comment: Не за что, но args могли бы тоже обозначить, а то из описания гадать, что такое args[0] - такое себе =)
Удачи!

Comment: Ок, в следующий раз обозначу и вам удачи!